# Spring SAML2 Sample Compilation Errors

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, saml-2.0

I have downloaded Spring **SAML2** core and sample projects. When trying to compile the sample project in eclipse, it shows errors.

For example, in the class `org.springframework.security.saml.web.MetadataController` there are references to `MetadataGenerator.setEntityAlias(..)` that do not resolve.

I checked the source code of `MetadataGenerator` in **SAML2** Core project and there is no such method.

What am I missing?

Comment: You must be using older code, these methods moved to it's subclass in RC3. Try using the latest jar "spring-security-saml2-core.1.0.0.RELEASE".

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me with 1.0.0.RC2 and not later versions.

Pointing to the following repository:

```
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```